# Solicit response pattern and its usage

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I was reading about message exchange patterns (MEP) in web services.
I came across a pattern called `Solicit Response`.

I googled it but did not find much information about it and its usage.
Can anyone give me the details about this and its usage scenarios.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

A solicit/response operation is an operation in which the service endpoint sends a message and expects to receive an answering message in response.

[image]

- This is the opposite of the request/response operation since the
  service endpoint is initiating the operation (soliciting the client),
  rather than responding to a request.
- Solicit/response is similar to notification messaging, except that
  the client is expected to respond to the Web service.
- With this type of messaging the  element first declares an
   tag and then a  message definition – exactly the
  reverse of a request/response operation.

An example of this operation might be a service that sends out order status to a client and receives back a receipt.

Answer (score 1):

The **solicit-response** operation includes one `output` element, which is the server's request to the client, followed by one `input` element, which is the client's response back to the server.

**Figure: The Solicit-response message pattern**
[image]

Sample WSDL operation type for solict/response. This operation consists of one `output` message and one `input` message.

```
<operation name="weatherUpdateRenew">
  <output message="tns:RenewRequest"/>
  <input message="tns:RenewResponse"/>
</operation>
```

[Source](http://docs.roguewave.com/hydraexpress/4.3.0/html/rwsfexpwsfabricationug/9-2.html)